# Removing the image from an IKImageView

Tags: objective-c, quartz-2d, ikimageview

I have an IKImageView that is coming up effectively un-initialized. This is happening effectively in an error-state (The user is unregistered) so I haven't had a chance to put an image in it yet.

In 10.6, this comes up fine, with a black rectangle. In 10.5, however, it comes up with garbage. some rectangles of noise, some rectangles of copies of the desktop, etc. I've tried setting the ZoomFactor to 0.0, I've tried setting the image to nil, but it appears that the problem is beyond that.

any ideas? (My next kludge is going to be to ship tiny blank image with the app, and try to get it to load that... but that's kind of silly)

Answer (score 0):

Designing your product such that this view is not displayed when it has no content **to** display would be the most obvious course of action.